# OpenHelperManager :- Setting new helper class while using multiple helper classes in OpenHelperManager ORMLite android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, optimization, ormlite

I am using `ORMLite` framework on an android project and I am stuck while using `OpenHelperManager.getHelper()` on multiple `repo` classes.

Here is a brief of my code structure :-

`DatabaseHelper` class which is responsible for creating `database` and `tables`

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper{

    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "muffet.db";
    public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        // Creating tables
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Category.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Transaction.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Budget.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Category.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Transaction.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Budget.class, true);
            onCreate(database, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

`TransactionRepo` which is responsible for accessing database.

```
public class TransactionRepo extends DatabaseHelper {
    //    private Dao<Transaction, Integer> transactionDao = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Transaction, Integer> transactionRuntimeDao = null;

    public TransactionRepo(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RuntimeExceptionDao<Transaction, Integer> getTransactionRuntimeDao(){
        if(transactionRuntimeDao == null){
            transactionRuntimeDao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(Transaction.class);
        }
        return transactionRuntimeDao;
    }

    /**
     * Save Transaction to database
     */
    public void save(Transaction transaction){
        try {
            transactionRuntimeDao = getTransactionRuntimeDao();
            transactionRuntimeDao.createOrUpdate(transaction);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get all list of data
     */
    public List<Transaction> getAll(){
        try{
            transactionRuntimeDao = getTransactionRuntimeDao();
            return transactionRuntimeDao.queryForAll();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

`TransactionServiceImpl` which is a service class for getting data from the `TransactionRepo`

```
public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionService {

    TransactionRepo transactionRepo;

    @Override
    public void save(Transaction transaction, Activity activity) {


        transactionRepo = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(activity, TransactionRepo.class);
        transactionRepo.save(transaction);
        OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Transaction> getAll(Activity activity) {

        transactionRepo = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(activity, TransactionRepo.class);

        List<Transaction> transactionList = transactionRepo.getAll();

        OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();

        return transactionList;
    }
}
```

It works fine when I run it. But when I try to access some another `repository` class which extends `DatabaseHelper` , and use the `OpenHelperManager.getHelper()` like for example :-

```
CategoryRepo categoryRepo = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(activity, CategoryRepo.class);
```

I get error as `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Helper class was class com.muffet.persistence.repository.TransactionRepo but is trying to be reset to class com.muffet.persistence.repository.CategoryRepo`

This clearly means that the `OpenHelperManager` has saved instance of `TransactionRepo` and when I try to get and set it as `CategoryRepo` it is unable to cast or something like that.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can answer the question? Its been days and I am still stuck

Answer (score 0):

```
public static synchronized void releaseHelper() {
    instanceCount--;
    logger.trace("releasing helper {}, instance count = {}", helper, instanceCount);
    if (instanceCount <= 0) {
        if (helper != null) {
            logger.trace("zero instances, closing helper {}", helper);
            helper.close();
            helper = null;
            wasClosed = true;
        }
        if (instanceCount < 0) {
            logger.error("too many calls to release helper, instance count = {}", instanceCount);
        }
    }
}
```

The releasetHelper method did not reset helperClass static menber:

```
private static Class<? extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper> helperClass = null;
```

So when you want to getHelper of another class, as below said:

```
private static void innerSetHelperClass(Class<? extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper> openHelperClass) {
    // make sure if that there are not 2 helper classes in an application
    if (openHelperClass == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Helper class was trying to be reset to null");
    } else if (helperClass == null) {
        helperClass = openHelperClass;
    } else if (helperClass != openHelperClass) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Helper class was " + helperClass + " but is trying to be reset to "
                + openHelperClass);
    }
}
```

Thus even your previous helperclass('helperClass') is parent of your later helperclass('openHelperClass'), but still, not equal. That's the reason for exception you seen.

My suggestion is to call

`OpenHelperManager.setOpenHelperClass(CategoryRepo.class);`

before

`CategoryRepo categoryRepo = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(activity, CategoryRepo.class);`